# git submodule "--reference" parameter

Tags: git, git-submodules

In the [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) documentation for `git submodule add`, it shows that there is a `--reference` parameter. Presumably, this works the same way the `--reference` parameter for `git clone` works, by copying objects from it, instead of the remote repository. After executing with this parameter, if I look inside `.git/modules/<submodule>/objects/info`, there is an `alternates` file, containing the path to the reference repo.

However, `git clone` also has a [`--dissociate`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---dissociate) parameter, to essentially do this for only the initial clone. Is there a way to the same thing for a submodule repository?

Comment: With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), yes, there is a way to do the same thing for a submodule repository. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671521/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`git submodule update`" and "`git submodule add`" supported the "`--reference`" option to borrow objects from a neighbouring local repository like "`git clone`" does, but lacked the more recent invention "`--dissociate`".

That is no longer the case with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018)

> submodule: add `--dissociate` option to add/update commands
>
> Add `--dissociate` option to add and update commands, both clone helper commands that already have the `--reference` option `--dissociate` pairs with.

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a0ef29341accafa51345e90225d87f6a0d297b7b/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L366-L378) now adds:

> ```
> --dissociate::
> ```
>
> This option is only valid for `add` and `update` commands.
> These commands sometimes need to clone a remote repository. In this case, this option will be passed to the `git clone` command.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only way to do this is to run `git repack -a -d` in the submodule directory after cloning it with `--reference`.

I guess a future Git version might add direct support for `--dissociate` to `git submodule {add,update}` itself, but it doesn't exist in the latest (2.15) version yet.